# Disable JS Syntax check in Domino Designer

Tags: javascript, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

My Domino Designer performs an automatic JS syntax check and only serves "valid" JS files. I can replace the old valid file in the packet explorer, but as long as the new file is not valid, the old one is still served to the requesting browser.

Where valid is up to the viewer, and browsers, when served with that very file by Apache or IIS, parse that "invalid" JS file and work with it.

I now need exactly this "invalid" JS file served.

How do I disable JS Syntax check in Domino Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the file as a file resource instead of where the JS files are generally stored (Code\Script Libraries). Then you can serve to whomever, however you want. This applies to minified files also as they generally do not pass the validator process.

Comment: I have put the JS file in a subfolder of the the WebContent Directory using Package explorer. How/where would I put them instead?

Comment: There is a "Resources / Files" design element category. Files in there can be referenced by a URL with the {<nsfFilePath>/<fileResourceName>}